# Facebook "Validation failed. The field could not be validated."

Tags: facebook

I keep getting this message when I try to modify my Facebook app. And it happens even if I try to save changes without modifying it:

Validation failed.
The field could not be validated.

But it doesnt tell me which field is causing the problem!

Only thing that changed was that one of the administrators deleted himself from the list to reinstall the app and see how it'd work for a new user.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: I removed some pending user invites, and it started working. Weird.

I hope this helps someone in the future.